# In Ionic, why doesn't the routing work on iPhone, but works on built version and on ionic serve

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, routes

I have an app (that - by the way - communicates with `node.js` server), in ionic and routing and login page works for `ionic serve` version, but fails to run as an iPhone app. The problem is that I can run the app on iPhone and see the login page, but when I set the correct credentials and press OK, I am not routed to the next page (which is the default page that goes when user logs in), so I don't know where the bug is. I tried to build the app with `index.html` having `base href="/"` and `base href="."` and that didn't work. What else can I try? This is code in app.module.ts that has definition of routing module:

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
```

and then also it has the imports part:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule, 
    SharedModule,
  ],
```

next, this is related code in ap-routing.module:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { AuthGuard } from "./services/auth.guard";

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "streams",
        loadChildren: "./components/streams/streams.module#StreamsModule",
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
```

StreamsModule relevant code:

```
import { StreamsRoutingModule } from './streams-routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from './../../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [StreamsComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    StreamsRoutingModule
  ]
})
```

This is the code that is triggered on login:

```
loginUser() {
        this.showSpinner = true;
        this.authService.loginUser(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.tokenService.SetToken(data.token);
                this.loginForm.reset();
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.router.navigate(["streams"]);
                }, 3000);
            },
            err => {
                this.showSpinner = false;

                if (err.error.message) {
                    this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

finally, the routes variable in streams routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: StreamsComponent
    },
    {
        path: "streams",
        component: StreamsComponent
    },
    {
        path: "**",
        redirectTo: "streams",
        pathMatch: "full"
    }
];
```

This is the authguard:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { TokenService } from "./token.service";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router, private tokenService: TokenService) {}

    canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        const token = this.tokenService.GetToken();
        if (token) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(["/"]);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, during the log in process on ios app, while inspecting using safari developer mode, I can see the http traffic from the app on my iPhone, and I can see that the calls are being made and proper response is retrieved, i.e. I am logged in, but, the screen freezes on the login page. Why is the routing not working properly on the ios app and works correct on the `ionic server` version?

Comment: Does it work in Safari on desktop?

Comment: It does work. I've just checked.

Comment: What is inside your `AuthGuard` service?

Comment: I added the AuthGuard, in the question.

Comment: THe Auth Guard was the cause, I simplified it by just returning true, and it passes on the routing now works. I have other issues, but this one is resolved thanks. You can post the answer, and you will get the bounty, @TomislavStankovic

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic I'm glad I was able to help you to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the `AuthGuard` service, as it turned out. Guard returns a boolean result. If the user is logged in, it returns true and the navigation continues.

> The Auth Guard was the cause, I simplified it by just returning true,
>   and it passes on the routing now works.

I'm glad I was able to help you to come up with a solution.

---

P.S. Additionally, if you want to prevent the application from loading the entire module if the user is not authorized to do so you can use `canLoad()`. For example:

```
canLoad() {
    return this._storage.get('userLogged').then(res => {
      if (res) {
        this.router.navigate(['/example-route']);
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    });
}
```